# PM getting a feel for the time a Drupal site takes

Tags: drupal, project-management

I'm PM'ing a project running drupal and we're trying to get an estimate of how long certain aspects are going to take.

For this question, I'm not really asking how long it would take to build a Drupal "SITE" per se'...just one very specific aspect of it.

We are doing custom CSS and styling for a page (NO THEMES). And we have about 20 different styles of pages to do.

So, with that in mind...assuming all the content has been migrated, the Drupal backend and modules have been installed and configured...how long PER PAGE would be a reasonable estimate to CSS and style a page such as this one...?

http://giantlife.com/

AGAIN, not the whole site or the content or the backend modules...JUST styling out the custom page layout for one page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on many things.

First: How well does the structure of the drupal site match the design. If the structure of the site differs a lot from the design, you could very well need an extra 4 to 8 hours for styling the page.

Second: How much styling do you already have? Do you need to build it from the ground, or is there already a lot of styling present and do you only need to change some aspects of the page.

Third: How fast is your developer. Some developers are able to make certain things in 8 hours, which takes others 2 or 3 times as long.

So what you're actually asking is, how long does it take to make a car, without specifying what it should do, or how it should look.

Long story short, we don't know enough to make a suitable estimate, and even if we would know enough, the estimate still wouldn't really be relevant, because it might be true to the person making the estimate, but that doesn't mean that the person actually realising it, is as fast.

But if I had to make an estimate based on what you've told me, I'd say I'd need about 6 - 8 hours to style the layout of one custom page. But that is a guesstimate.

Answer (score 0):

If you're truly a PM on this and not a developer, I would suggest involving your developers in the estimation process. First, break down the larger job into smaller more management chucks. Then, work, with developers to estimate the amount of time each chunk will take.  SCRUM has a great approach for this.